# Output difference between MacTeX 2015 and 2017 with powerdot class

Tags: landscape, dvi, dvips, powerdot

I upgraded MacTeX on my laptop from the 2015 distribution to the basic 2017 distribution. After installing the required packages, I tried to compile one of my slide decks which use the powerdot class, from DVI through PS and finally to PDF (`latex` then `dvips` then `ps2pdf13`). This worked fine before (in the 2015 distribution), with the output in landscape and filling the full page. With the 2017 distribution, the output comes out in portrait, with a cropped version of the actual slides taking up about 30% of the upper part of the page, with the rest of the page totally blank.

I traced this to a difference in `dvips` (version 5.995 in the 2015 distribution and 5.997 in the 2017 distribution). Regardless of whether `latex` is run in the 2015 or 2017 version to output the DVI file, it's possible to get the correct output when running `dvips` 5.995 from the 2015 distribution, and the wrong output when running `dvips` 5.997 from the 2017 distribution.

It's interesting to look at the beginning of the Postscript file in each case. For `dvips` 5.995, the relevant part is:

```
%%Orientation: Landscape
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 594 792
```

As for the `dvips` 5.997 output, `%%Orientation: Landscape` is missing, and the bounding box line is replaced by `%%BoundingBox: 0 0 1584 1188`.

Other than manually replacing `dvips` by the older version (or perhaps looking for an even newer version), is there something that can be done to fix the output?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please add a minimal example to play with?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just after posting the question, I found a [MiKTeX bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2577/#464b) that describes the same issue, and indicates the fix: adding `-L0` to the `dvips` invocation. This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

> The solution is to update to at least the 2017-07-23 version `powerdot`.

Using TeX Live 2017

### Test file

```
%%
%% This is file `powerdot-example1.tex',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% powerdot.dtx  (with options: `pdexample1')
%% 
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Copyright (C) 2005-2008 Hendri Adriaens, Chris Ellison; 2009-2015 Hendri Adriaens
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%
%% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
%% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is in
%%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2003/12/01 or later.
%%
%% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%%
%% This Current Maintainer of this work is Hendri Adriaens.
%%
%% This work consists of all files listed in manifest.txt.
%%
\documentclass{powerdot}

\title{powerdot example 1}
\author{Hendri Adriaens \and Christopher Ellison}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{slide}{Slide 1}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item This is the first slide\pause
    \item There is nothing special about it.
  \end{itemize}
\end{slide}

\section{First section}

\begin{slide}{Slide 2}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item<1-> Here
    \begin{itemize}
      \item<2-> we
      \begin{itemize}
        \item<3-> demonstrate
        \begin{itemize}
          \item<4-> the itemize environment
        \end{itemize}
      \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{slide}

\begin{slide}{Slide 3}
  \begin{enumerate}[type=1]
    \item<1> Here
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item<2> we
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item<3> demonstrate
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item<4> the enumerate environment
        \end{enumerate}
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{slide}

\end{document}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `powerdot-example1.tex'.
```

### Before today's (2017-07-23) update to `powerdot`:

[image]

### After update

[image]